# Network traffic peaks for Bitcoin Core GUI Node

Tags: bitcoin-core, network

I have the latest version installed, no SOCKS5 connexion.
Sending maximum is around 4500Ko/s (also seeable on the picture).
Do you know why it goes up like that ?[image]

Comment: Does someone could explain these data sending around 4000Ko/s ?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/87741)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that's a graph of network activity attributable to bitcoin-qt.

My hypothesis for the sharp peaks would be that there is a low level of chatter where the node finds out whether peers have new data using small inventory messages. Occasionally a peer has new data and the peaks might represent the actual bulk transfer of that newly discovered data in larger data messages.

The newly discovered data could arise from newly created unconfirmed transactions or from newly mined blocks.

I suppose the only way to actually confirm this would be to correlate the network activity with bitcoin log entries.

I would use Wireshark or another network-sniffer to capture and decode the data being sent & received. I believe Wireshark has protocol decoders for Bitcoin traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the Wireshark tips.

Usually, I don't have a lot of peaks like that,, it was only one or two on the 5min chart.

The main question remain on the fact that on my other computer, I have a maximum sending around 100Ko/s. I say around because on the one I took the picture on this topic,, maximum sending is around 4000Ko/s. 
Does someone already have this differences or could explain them ?